# Add the first day of each month to year month date in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dataframe that contains 3 columns year month and SPEI value
I want to add day column that contains the first day of each month
[image: this is an example]

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need new column with first `day` use:

```
df['day'] = 1
```

If need datetime with first day:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month']].assign(day=1))
```